# Можно ли в WebView включить прием оповещений

Tags: android, webview

Можно ли в приложении webview получать push-оповещения . Интересует именно получение разрешение на отправку, как обычно это в хроме происходит.
Просто в моем приложении не происходит запроса прав. 
Это можно как-то исправить ?

Answer (score 0):

По информации отсюда https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API
в данный момент WebView не поддерживает это API (Push API).
Я бы рекомендовал вам интегрировать родную имплементацию и прокидывать события внутрь webview из обработчика.

Например если используете CordovaIonic - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-fork